# Does glob() have negation?

Tags: php, glob

I know I can do this...

```
glob('/dir/somewhere/*.zip');
```

...to get all files ending in `.zip`, but is there a way to return all files that are *not* ZIPs?

Or should I just iterate through and filter off ones with that extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think glob can do a "not-wildcard"...

I see at least two other solutions :

- use a combinaison of [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) / [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) / [`closedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php)
- Or use some SPL Iterator ; To be more specific, I'm thinking about [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) ; and maybe you can combine it with some [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) ?

Comment: How about reading all the files using glob and then parse the results, the results that fit the exclude pattern are ignored and the rest get added into a list

Answer (score 28):

You could always try something like this:

```
$all = glob('/dir/somewhere/*.*');
$zip = glob('/dir/somewhere/*.zip');
$remaining = array_diff($all, $zip);
```

Although, using one of the other methods Pascal mentioned might be more efficient.

Comment: I have a suspicion the performance overhead could be somewhat substantial on large directories/arrays, however, it is definitely the most elegant example. +1

Comment: Why do you expect there to be large performance overhead?

Answer (score 18):

A quick way would be to `glob()` for everything and use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) to filter out the files that you do not want.

```
preg_grep('#\.zip$#', glob('/dir/somewhere/*'), PREG_GREP_INVERT)
```

Also see [Glob Patterns for File Matching in PHP](http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/)

Answer (score 9):

This pattern will work:

```
glob('/dir/somewhere/*.{?,??,[!z][!i][!p]*}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

which finds everything in /dir/somewhere/ ending in a dot followed by either

- one character (`?`)
- or two characters  (`??`)
- or anything not starting with the consecutive letter z,i,p (`[!z][!i][!p]*`)

Comment: Sorry @Gordon, -1. This finds everything in `/dir/somewhere/` ending in a dot followed by three characters (not including `zip`). It will **not** match longer or shorter file extensions.

Comment: @salathe hmm. thanks. Updated the description. Actually, I was trying to make it work with `{!zip}` but apparently PHP does not support it? Could the above be mixed with braces?

Comment: *Could the above be mixed with braces?* Yes, it could. For example, `*.{?,??,[!z][!i][!p]*}`

Comment: @salathe I'll replace my pattern with this then if you dont mind (since you came up with).

Comment: don't forget the `GLOB_BRACE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "/path";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($d = opendir($dir)) {
           while (($file = readdir($d)) !== false) {
                if ( substr($file, -3, 3) != "zip" ){
                    echo "filename: $file \n";
                }
           }
        closedir($d);
    }
}
```

NB: "." and ".." not taken care of. Left for OP to complete