# Delete all but one filetype from directory using glob php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does glob() have negation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877524/does-glob-have-negation)

I want to delete all files from a directory (could be any number of file extentions) apart from the single index.html in there.

I'm using:

```
$path = "/assets/cache/";

foreach(glob($path ."*.*") as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

But can't for the life of me how to say unlink, if not .html!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this here...

```
$path = "/assets/cache/";

foreach(glob($path ."*.*") as $file) {
    $pathPart = explode(".",$file);
    $fileEx = $pathPart[count($pathPart)-1];
    if($fileEx != "html" && $fileEx != "htm"){
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a bloomin genius. Perfect!!

Comment: Happy to help my friend. If you got the answer you needed don't forget to accept (: Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't accept at the time as it said i had to wait 4 more minutes!  Gahh! I've just come back now and accepted it! I wouldn't forget your kind help :)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
$path = "/assets/cache/";

foreach(glob($path ."*.*") as $file) {
    if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'html') {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

if you want to delete other html files also (apart from "index.html"):

```
$path = "/assets/cache/";

foreach(glob($path ."*.*") as $file) {
    if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME) != 'index.html') {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The php function [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) has no negation, however PHP can give you the difference between two globs via [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
$all = glob("*.*");
$not = glob("php_errors.log");

var_dump(
    $all, 
    $not, 
    array_diff($all, $not)
);
```

See the demo: http://codepad.org/RBFwPUWm

If you do not want to use arrays, I highly suggest to take a look into PHPs directory iterators.